# Case sensitive in data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Well it must be late and my brain got numb. How come jQuery doesn't recognize case sensitive in data attribute? I faced this annoying problem:

**HTML:**

```
<a data-showId="12345">Test 1</a>
```

**Javascript:**

```
console.log($('a').data('showId'));
console.log($('a').data('showid'));
```

The first line is **undefined** and second returned **12345** correctly. I thought it supposed to returned correctly in first line and undefined in second. So does it mean all data- attr must be lowercase?

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/7dExt/1/

Comment: You could use: `$('a').attr('data-showId')` which isn't case sensitive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it has to do with the fact that [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#data-%2a) explicitly prevents the data key from having capital A to Z letters.

- the name must not start with xml, whatever case is used for these letters;
- the name must not contain any semicolon (U+003A);
- the name must not contain capital A to Z letters.

In the data-* naming scheme, a data attribute like `data-show-id` will be accessible in javascript using the key `showId`, because of this limitation the use of capital letters seems to be restricted in the key.

Also [read](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#attr-data):

> All attributes on HTML elements in HTML documents get ASCII-lowercased
>   automatically, so the restriction on ASCII uppercase letters doesn't
>   affect such documents