# Why Is .data not Working?

Tags: c#, jquery

Newbie here, I've been on this for over 2 hours! :(

If anyone can tell me why this isn't working I will be forever indebted to you :)

```
            @foreach (var c in Model.Cleaner.TimeConfirmations)
            {   
<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle cancelTime thex" data-timeid="12"></label>
                 }

            }
```

then jquery

```
$(".thex").on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data("timeId")
    alert(id);

});
```

why is id undefined?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: Probably because in the html you have `timeid` and in the javascript you have `timeId`, different case on the second I

Comment: Wow! What's your address? And who should I make the check out to? :)

Comment: My name and address are the same, the red cross, feel free to make out a big check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case sensitive error.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/f5hym7yh/)

```
$(".thex").on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).data("timeid")
    alert(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` function retrieves an element's data attribute value in the following way, the `data("timeid")` matches `data-timeid` attribute and `data("timeId")` matches `data-time-id`

If you want to use camelCase `timeId` to retrieve its value then you need to write it as follows,

```
<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle cancelTime thex" data-time-id="12"></label>
```

The **hyphen** character in HTML identifies it as camelCase.

Alternatively you can use `attr` function to get an attribute's value it does a case insensitive search. For more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19653266/case-sensitive-in-data-attribute)

Check the below code snippet, I hope it will be of help to you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".thex").on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data("timeid")
    console.clear();
    console.log('data function: ' + id);
    console.log('attr function: ' + $(this).attr('data-timeId'));
  });

  $(".thex-alt").on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).data("timeId");
    console.clear();
    console.log('data function: ' + id);
  });
});
```

```css
label {
  padding: 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle cancelTime thex" data-timeid="12">lowercase [data-timeid="12"]</label>
<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle cancelTime thex" data-timeid="12">lowercase [data-timeid="12"]</label>
<label class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle cancelTime thex-alt" data-time-id="12">camelCase [data-time-id="12"]</label>
```