# Getting 'undefined' or 'NaN' for data-addval when trying to get is as number in JS

Tags: javascript, html, undefined, nan

I'm building a simple web game and I've been struggling with a problem for hours. No matter how I try to access the data-addval attribute in my JavaScript code, it always returns 'undefined' or 'NaN' when it should be a number. The issue seems to be related to extracting the 'addval' value from an HTML input element. Below is an example of the HTML code and the relevant parts of my main.js file.

`<input type="button".... class="btnU" data-cost="100" data-addval="1" data-progress="0.0001"/>`

```js
const upgradeButtonsContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".btnU");

upgradeButtonsContainer.forEach((upgradeButton) => {
    upgradeButton.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        const upgradeButtonData = e.target.dataset;
        console.log("Before calling upgrade: addVal =", upgradeButtonData.addVal);
        upgrade(parseInt(upgradeButtonData.cost), Number(upgradeButtonData.addVal), parseFloat(upgradeButtonData.progress));
    });
});
```

```js
function upgrade(cost, addVal, progress) {
    if (clicks >= cost) {
        console.log("Before upgrade: value =", value, "clicks =", clicks, "addVal =", addVal);

        clicks = clicks - cost;
        console.log("After deducting cost: clicks =", clicks);

        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = clicks.toFixed(2);

        value += Number(addVal); // Convert addVal to a number using Number function
        console.log("After upgrade: value =", value);

        document.getElementById("clickValue").innerHTML = "Click Value: " + value;

        newMultiplayer = newMultiplayer + progress;
        
        console.log("After upgrading newMultiplayer =", newMultiplayer);
    }
}
```

What I've Tried:
I've attempted to retrieve the 'addVal' value using parseInt, Number(), and parseFloat() methods but it still returns 'undefined'. I've also checked that the 'data-addval' attribute in the HTML code is correctly formatted, at least i think it is. I also tried multiple other ways of getting the addval from the html code but they all failed (I also tried changing the V in addval to upper-case and lower-case)

Browser Console Output:
After clicking the 'upgrade' button, here are the relevant console logs:

```
Before calling upgrade: addVal = undefined
main.js:382 Before upgrade: value = 1 clicks = 100000 addVal = NaN
main.js:385 After deducting cost: clicks = 99100
main.js:390 After upgrade: value = NaN
main.js:396 After upgrading newMultiplayer = 1.0003
```

Any help or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `addVal` should be `addval`. `addVal` would be correct if you used `data-add-val`.

Comment: "I also tried changing the V in addval to upper-case and lower-case". Did you change it in your JS code or your HTML code? In your HTML code, your data attribute is named `addval` while you're referencing it in JS as `addVal`. Camelcase is only required if the data attribute was named `add-val`. Please see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2dhtk3Lq/1/). If that didn't point you in the right direction, please update the question with more information, preferably a [minimal, **reproducible** example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Data attributes are case-sensitive, with a dash adding an uppercase letter to the JavaScript property. You can either use:

```
Number(upgradeButtonData.addval)
```

with your existing code or change the attributes in your HTML to `data-add-val="1"` (notice the dash) to access it via `.addVal`. You can read more about how and why data attributes have that kind of casing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19653369/8517948).

You could also just use `getAttribute("data-addval")` or similar to access the data attributes instead.

More on data attributes and accessing them can be found [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access).

Comment: Yeah, I can't belive it was such i silly mistake. So sorry and thank you!